# Pandas, sorting transactions into categories

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort transactions in a pandas dataframe,  I have a dictionary with a category for key, and a list of vendors as the value.

basically, what i'm trying to achieve, is to sorting the transactions by evaluating the description to see if it contains a value in one of the dictionary lists, and assigning the corresponding dict key category to the Category column.

Current code,  the problem i'm having, is it returns a None value to my entire category column.  I know i'm close, the function just doesn't update the category column

```
        for key, vendors in categories_dict.items():
            for vendor in vendors:

                def to_key(description):
                    if vendor in description:
                        return key

                df["Category"] = df.Description.apply(lambda x: to_key(x))
```

```
categories_dict = {categoty1 : ['VENDOR1', 'VENDOR2', 'VENDOR3']
        category2 : ['VENDOR4', 'VENDOR5', 'VENDOR6']
        category3 : ['VENDOR7', 'VENDOR8', 'VENDOR9']}
```

my dataframe looks currently similar to this:

| Date | Descript | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/20 | VENDOR1 #342 | 99.54 | NaN |
| 05/11/20 | VENDOR2 #762 | 100.5 | NaN |
| 06/11/20 | VENDOR4 #321 | 16.54 | NaN |
| 06/11/20 | VENDOR12 #57 | 32.54 | NaN |
| 09/11/20 | VENDOR7 #222 | 75.54 | NaN |

Desired result:

| Date | Descript | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/20 | VENDOR1 #342 | 99.54 | Category1 |
| 05/11/20 | VENDOR2 #762 | 100.5 | Category1 |
| 06/11/20 | VENDOR4 #321 | 16.54 | Category2 |
| 06/11/20 | VENDOR12 #57 | 32.54 | NaN |
| 09/11/20 | VENDOR7 #222 | 75.54 | Category3 |

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes every description is of the form "VendorX #ABC".

[image]

```
dic = {"category1" : ['VENDOR1', 'VENDOR2', 'VENDOR3'],
    "category2" : ['VENDOR4', 'VENDOR5', 'VENDOR6'],
    "category3" : ['VENDOR7', 'VENDOR8', 'VENDOR9']}
new_dic = {}
for key, val in dic.items():
    for vendor in val:
        new_dic[vendor] = key
new_dic
```

[image]

```
def get_category(description):
    return description.split("#")[0].strip()

df["Category"] = df.Descript.apply(lambda x: new_dic.get(get_category(x)))
df
```

[image]

Comment: This solution assumes every description is of the form "VendorX #ABC". Let me know if that is not always the case.

Comment: unfortunately it is not always the case